# Unfamiliar @interface statement

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, interface

I came across an interface that was defined as shown below:

```
@interface UITableViewCell (XXXXXXXX) <MHLazyTableImageCell>
@end
```

Can someone explain what the value in the parentheses `(XXXXXXX)` does? I have not seen an interface of this format.

Comment: This is one of the posts about Objective-C Categories. http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-categories.html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means `XXXXXXX` is a category. It adds or modifies functionality to/of the `UITableViewCell` class. You can read about categories [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html).

As an addition, the category conforms to the `MHLazyTableImageCell` protocol.